# How to add four timestamps together

Tags: android, date, timestamp

Have this tiny question.
I am taking the hours and minutes using a timepicker and are setting the time in four different edittexts. Now I wonder how I can add these times together and get a total value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any luck? If so, please share your answer.

I've been on and off looking at it and the easiest/most comfortable --for myself-- way I found was to operate the milliseconds directly, then converting to Timestamp again.

```
Timestamp sum = new Timestamp(first.getTime() + second.getTime() +
                               third.getTime() + fourth.getTime());
```

That is if you are using `java.sql.Timestamp`.